# Find point of minimum total travel distance from a set of locations using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, distance

I have a list of addresses and I would like to find a point that has the minimum total **travel distance** (got by using Google Distance Matrix Service) to all addresses in the list.

For example: I have a list of all employees' addresses and I would like to find a place for the new office. The total driving distance from all employees' home to the new office should be minimum.

I think about try every road intersection point then compare the result, but I don't know how to get list of road intersections nearby.

How can I do that with Google Maps API? Thank you very much!

Comment: To find the center of the irregular shape that would be constructed by these points, you would find the average latitude and longitude for the set. The result would be the "center". You could then search for places within a radius of that location. You might be able to convert each location into a vector (weighted by the travel distance, being that there is no such thing as a direct route), and find the averages using these adjusted values.

Comment: I think calculate the average latitude and longitude for the set won't always return the corect "center". Let take 3 points from a line, A, B and C (B is in the middle of the line connect A and C). The true center should be the center point of AC. When calculating the average, it would be some point between the center point of AC and B.

Comment: Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/UCHCs/  The red square is the average of the coordinates. The black square is the average of the extremities.